# Converting a FLIR image CSV to TIFF using Python

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, remote-sensing, csv, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I have a geolocated CSV file containing one lat, long coordinate for the entire thermal image. I would like to convert this CSV to a TIFF using Python so that each pixel contains a temperature. All the posts I have viewed online deal with a CSV file which has coordinates for each pixel stored in columns of lat and long. With just one pair of coordinates, I am unsure how to do this.

Here is an example of my data, the columns are temperature values of pixels but there are no lat, long coordinates because the image itself is only associated with one lat, long coordinate:

```
EXAMPLE
Frame 1: 0.812, 0.930, 1.375
         0.932, 0.714, 1.342
         0.899, 0.767, 0.987
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe. You would need to know if the single latitude and longitude value you have is the center of the image or a corner? This might be problematic- if you have drone imagery the lat/long is likely the aircraft location and the pitch, roll, and yawl of the camera at the time of capture my not have resulted in an image that is not rectangular.

You would also need to know the spatial resolution of the desired output TIFF.  Are the temperature values a foot apart, five meters apart?  If you had this info you could convert your lat and long to UTM coordinates and build an ASCII text file with the header information as shown here https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/esri-ascii-raster-format.htm#GUID-B099F30E-BA69-4DC4-8766-8F2799996422. ESRI products and QGIS can both display ASCII Grid data.

Another approach might be be to just make up the ASCII header information  coordinate and cell size data (but with the proper number of columns and rows) then use a GIS to georeference the TIFF.  Maybe you have a related RGB image from your camera that will help with the georeferencing of the faux-ascii.